# How do I add dynamic property to root project in Gradle 2.x/3.x

Tags: gradle

I am migrating few gradle scripts built using 1.x in to 3.3. I found the way adding dynamic properties changed in Gradle 2.x/3.x

Used to add simply by defining the property at the top level.

```
foo = "dev"
```

How do I add dynamic property to root project  in Gradle 2.x/3.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the answer. We now have a cleaner separation

```
project.ext.env= "dev"
task doStuff {
    println ext.${env}
}
```